# Can I update values in an ObservableCollection<T> without destroying and adding new items?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got this issue with my WPF application -- I'm using an `ObservableCollection<T>` to bind the UI to a collection of players. This list gets updated every 10 seconds with new data streamed from a game server.  The problem is that blowing away the list and re-adding everything causes for some terrible UI inconsistencies:

- selected items become deselected
- context menus open become unbound and useless
- possibly some errors cropping up from all the item instances being lost

So I am asking if there is any way I can update values for an item that don't match the previous value.  I do still need it to be DataBinding friendly for the UI (auto updating on PropertyChanged).

Comment: from my knowledge the ObservableCollection<T> already implements INotifyChange interface therefore they are refreshed I think a code sample would be very helpful here .

Comment: I think ObservableCollection will only notify of items being added or removed--I don't think updating the actual items already in the collection will achieve this.  I think the item itself has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find the players in the collection, you can simply map the updated property values to them.  If the player itself implements INotifyPropertyChanged, it should work with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks Phil. What I ended up doing was allowing the Player class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and managed the updating of the items by not replacing them, but checking if they first exist, then updating them using this line of code. Player p = Team1List.Where(i => i.PlayerName == player.PlayerName).FirstOrDefault();  Then setting p to the updated player instance and it updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract the Player data into its own class and encapsulate the data in a wrapper.  For instance:

```
public sealed class PlayerData
{
    //Data related to the Player (possibly immutable)
}

public sealed class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PlayerData _data;

    //Mirror properties for information in data

    //Other functionality

    public void ChangeData(PlayerData newData)
    {
        _data = newData;
        //Trigger OnPropertyChanged(null) here to invalidate public state
    }
}
```

Now you can replace the data for the Player without having to invalidate the outer Player instance.  If you look closely, this is actually a kind of ViewModel for the underlying Player model.

Comment: I did implement the interface but it seems to work best in my case if I set the item to a new instance in the updating logic.  Thanks.